# Word/OpenXML - How do I create a hidden bookmark?

Tags: ms-word, vsto, openxml

I've not had any luck in either the OpenXML API or Word/VSTO API, finding a way to create or modify a bookmark's visibility. Even adding bookmarks manually in Word, there's no box to check to make the bookmark hidden. Although there *is* a checkbox in the Bookmarks dialog that lets you *show* hidden bookmarks.  So how are hidden bookmarks represented in the XML, and can you create them using the Open XML SDK? Or are they a legacy thing that MS no longer wants us to create?

Comment: Your name ("System.Cats.Lol") is my favorite ever on SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK so this is easier than I thought...you just precede the bookmark name with an underscore. Note that this can only be done programmatically, not when adding bookmarks manually in Word.

Iiiiiiiiinteresting....

**Update:** Another thing I found--before you can iterate or access hidden bookmarks in a [Bookmarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258509%28office.12%29.aspx) object, you must set its [ShowHidden](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb223470%28office.12%29.aspx) property to true.

PS - SO, if you have any control over your spelling dictionary, you might add "programmatically". Unless I'm spelling it wrong. :)

Comment: interesting indeed. you can go ahead and accept your answer with the hollow checkmark next to it.

Comment: Thanks--they make you wait two days before you can accept your own answer, is why it wasn't already. :)

Comment: ah, yeah, the two day wait thing. once i had a question i asked and about 5 minutes later discovered the answer. had to wait 2 days and got a few other (good, but not great) answers. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

I created normal bookmarks in word file and than converted them to hidden bookmark programmatically. As said above hidden bookmarks can only be created programmatically and their name precede by "_". When ever iterating the bookmarks list make sure `Bookmarks.ShowHidden` is set to true, otherwise hidden bookmarks will not show up in the list. Below is the code that I used to hide all the visible bookmarks. At the very end I also clear undo record to make sure user can not undo the changes I made. You may create the custom undo record delete the last action if you wish.

```
public static void hideAllBookmark(Document doc)
{
    String newName = null;
    Range newRange = null;
    bool backup = doc.Bookmarks.ShowHidden;
    doc.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = false;
            
    for (int i = doc.Bookmarks.Count; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (!doc.Bookmarks[i].Name.Substring(0, 1).Equals("_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            newName= "_" + doc.Bookmarks[i].Name;
            newRange = doc.Bookmarks[i].Range;
            doc.Bookmarks[i].Delete();
            doc.Bookmarks.Add(newName, newRange);
        }
    }
    doc.Bookmarks.ShowHidden = backup;
    doc.UndoClear();
}
```